# EH-Cache with Spring Cache manager not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, caching, ehcache

We have spring based(3.2.9.Release) java web application and use hibernate for db operations.
We currently have caching mechanism using Dynacache which is configured through WebSphere server and use jndi mapping. We retrieve all the content from database on first page load and store it in Dynacache. Since it is a external call every time, we wanted to implement Eh-Cache and improve the performance. But surprisingly the performance of Eh-Cache is lesser than Dynacache and takes long time to load the page. Below is the configuration we had for Eh-Cache:

**xml configuration:**

```
<bean id="cacheService" class="com.wlp.sales.ols.core.api.cache.CacheService"></bean>

<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>

<bean id="ehcache"
        class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/configs/EhCache/ehcache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true" />
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
    <ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
    monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <cache name="contentCache" 
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" 
        eternal="true" 
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
        timeToIdleSeconds="0" timeToLiveSeconds="0"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU" 
        transactionalMode="off">
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

**dependencies:**

```
<!-- ehCache -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

We have a cache implementation class which will generate cache key using get and put methods to retrieve from db and put into a cache map as key value pair.

```
public Object get(CdiRequest request) {
        Object cdiObject = cacheService.get(request.getContentElement()
                .getContentType(), keyBuilder.build(request));
        return cdiObject instanceof CdiResponse ? (CdiResponse) cdiObject
                : request;
}
```

**//Put method implementation:**

```
cacheService.put(cdiResponse.getCdiRequest().getContentElement()
                    .getContentType(),
                    keyBuilder.build(cdiResponse.getCdiRequest()), cdiResponse);
```

**Implementation class :**

```
 public class CacheService implements ApplicationContextAware{
    @Autowired
    private CacheManager cacheManager;
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public Object get(String applnName, Object key) {

            Cache  cache = cacheManager.getCache("contentCache");
            return cache.get(key);
      }

      public boolean put(String applnName, Object key, Object value) {
          Cache  cache =  cacheManager.getCache("contentCache");
          cache.put(key, value);
          return true;
      }
}
```

It takes almost 60 seconds to 80 seconds to load each page on refresh or reload whereas dynacache just takes 3-4 seconds. Please advise if anything is being done wrongly or could done in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't want to provide standard annotations for Cache in Spring, and use it in the method that is obtaining values from DB?:

```
@Cacheable(value="contentCache", key="#name")
```

So you can get your content from DB and store in cache? If something changes, you can use `CacheEvict`.

Comment: what will happen if i try just as @Cacheable(value="contentCache")... can u tell me the significance of key in this case

Comment: You need to put the key. Without key it will show you an error.

Comment: i implemented as u mentioned..without key it didnt show any error to me..still i called cacheable annotation to my dao method like this : @Cacheable(value="contentCache", key="#name") and also tried using : @Cacheable(value="contentCache", key="#methodName") methodName - generates my custom key.. i had the sysout inside my dao method to check if its printing even on re-load or refresh.. its printing on every pageload or refresh which means its not taking from contentcache.. is there anything i m still dng wrong ?

Comment: With this implementation, i completely taken off the reference of cacheService..i only have the dependencies in my pom.xml,ehcache.xml and xml bean configuration. As i mentioned in my previous comment, i m directly calling this annotation to my dao method which retrieves content from my database

Answer (score 0):

There are several things that can be improved:

1. At the configuration level

   - Do you really need the disk store? It adds overhead as content must be serialized / deserialized.
   - In case you need it, you need size the disk store bigger than the onheap one, as all mapping will exist in the disk store. So with the current configuration, you are effectively limiting the onheap size to `1000`.
2. At the usage level, you are effectively using the cache as an in memory store because you have no logic to handle the case where the mapping is not found. Now, maybe what you are caching is a known set of keys and smaller than the size you have set. Still, this might be a later cause of problems.

With regards to the performance concerns, you will need to provide more detailed information if you need help tracking what is the issue.

Comment: :thanks much for the reply.. i understand ur pt..but as of now..we are good with the configuration we have given for eh-cache..can i know what more detailed information you would need to track the issue..

Comment: More context: invoked code, some timings, logs indicating that the cache is effectively used. In short everything that clears up a config / setup issue and the clear indications that the cache related invocations are the ones actually burning up all the time.